# Does hadoop use folders and subfolders

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have started learning Hadoop and just completed setting up a single node as demonstrated in [hadoop 1.2.1 documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/single_node_setup.html)
Now I was wondering if

1. When files are stored in this type of FS should I use a hierachial mode of storage - like folders and sub-folders as I do in Windows or files are just written into as long as they have a unique name?
2. Is it possible to add new nodes to the single node setup if say somebody were to use it in production environment. Or simply can a single node be converted to a cluster without loss of data by simply adding more nodes and editing the configuration?
3. This one I can google but what the hell! I am asking anyway, sue me. What is the maximum number of files I can store in HDFS?

Comment: @climbage Thank you for your response. I want to store image files and possibly some videos on a single server with 1TB HDD and be able to expand in the future if need there be by adding more storage nodes to the server. I don't think I will need to use MapReduce or any other functionality included in Hadoop. I just need to know that I can increase storage by adding an extra machine to the cluster. Do you think this is a good approach or it's an over kill?

Comment: I think it depends.  HDFS is fault tolerant through redundancy (usually a replication factor of 3).  With this in mind, adding 2 machines will not increase your storage capacity at all, but it will make your cluster more tolerant to hardware failure.  You can set your replication factor to 1 which means if a single machine goes down you could potentially lose **all** of your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When files are stored in this type of FS should I use a hierachial mode of storage - like folders and sub-folders as I do in Windows or files are just written into as long as they have a unique name?

Yes, use the directories to your advantage.  Generally, when you run jobs in Hadoop, if you pass along a path to a directory, it will process all files in that directory.  So.. you really have to use them anyway.

> Is it possible to add new nodes to the single node setup if say somebody were to use it in production environment. Or simply can a single node be converted to a cluster without loss of data by simply adding more nodes and editing the configuration?

You can add/remove nodes as you please (unless by single-node, you mean pseudo-distributed... that's different)

> This one I can google but what the hell! I am asking anyway, sue me. What is the maximum number of files I can store in HDFS?

Lots

Answer (score 0):

To expand on climbage's answer:

Maximum number of files is a function of the amount of memory available to your Name Node server. There is some loose guidance that each metadata entry in the Name Node requires somewhere between 150-200 bytes of memory (it alters by version).

From this you'll need to extrapolate out to the number of files, and the number of blocks you have for each file (which can vary depending on file and block size) and you can estimate for a given memory allocation (2G / 4G / 20G etc), how many metadata entries (and therefore files) you can store.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I want to store image files and possibly some videos on a single server with 1TB HDD and be able to expand in the future if need there be by adding more storage nodes to the server. I don't think I will need to use MapReduce or any other functionality included in Hadoop. I just need to know that I can increase storage by adding an extra machine to the cluster. Do you think this is a good approach or it's an over kill?

Comment: If you only intend on storing files, and initially on only a single node, and you're not going to be doing any map reduce against those those then Haodop / HDFS does feel like an overkill. Wouldn't it just be cheaper to add more HDDs to increase the storage on your machine, and make the drives into a RAID array if you want data redundancy?